# Storyboard "Main", but didn't get a UITableView when using UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, xcode-storyboard

I have been going through this [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-crafting-custom-uitableview-cells--mobile-15702), "Option 2: Prototype Cells"
I implimented all the steps, but, the following code gives me an error:

```
@interface MTViewController : UITableViewController

@end
```

the error message is:

> instantiated view controller with identifier "UIViewController-BYZ-38-t0r" from storyboard "Main", but didn't get a UITableView.'

Here is what I tried - I changed `UITableViewController` to `UIViewController` and the error went away. But, the tableview remains blank. Can you tell me why this is ?

Comment: What do you mean blank? When you add a View Controller to your storyboard it's vanilla. You have to add the elements to it.

Answer (score 49):

In your storyboard, you need to make the root view of your `UITableViewController` a `UITableView`.

[image: Interface Builder Table View Controller]

[image: Interface Builder Custom Class]

Answer (score 19):

Try changing your super class to UIViewController or change the controller in your storyboard to TableView Controller

```
@interface MTViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate

@end
```

Answer (score 8):

Drag a new instance of Table View Controller into your storyboard, copy the cells you created in your previous controller into the new one.

This error occurred probably because you used the default UIViewController created by XCode which isn't a UITableViewController.

Comment: very subtle problem and obvious solution (assuming you appreciate the problem).  now, why are my cell properties coming back NIL?

Comment: this is wierd but it's true. Had the same problem, solved like you described

Answer (score 8):

I met exactly the same issue as you.
You're probably using a UIViewController instead of a UITableViewController in the storyboard.

NOTE: 
**Only subclass a custom UITableViewController in the storyboard is not enough**. You'll see the difference:
[difference between UIViewController and UITableViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaigN.png)

So you have to drag out a UITableViewController from the library, then move all things(cells) to it. Don't forget to check bindings and auto layouts if broken.

And of course you cannot move the tableview to the root of UIViewController, it just doesn't work like that. =)

Answer (score 5):

Actually you are using UIViewController not UITableViewController. Delete your default view controller and drag new TableViewController in your storyboard. Because your ViewController not having TableView, but it's trying to load cells.

Simple solution is : **Delete ViewController and add TableViewController**

Then you have to change its class name to **MTViewController** or **Your Class Name**

Answer (score 3):

I've had this problem too. I created originally plain `UIViewController` then i decided to rather use `UITableViewController`. Problem is that i forgot to set storyboard ID on new controller, and change it to something else on the old controller, otherwise you will instantiate the old controller from storyboard and this problem will occur.

Answer (score 2):

In the storyboard just change the class of your ViewController to your new class name which here is `MTViewController` - [image of steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njNUh.png)

Answer (score 0):

make sure the dataSource is set to self.

Comment: Can you be more precise, or even share some code that helps to understand your answer?

Comment: Use comment for this kind of info.