# Cannot connect/perform segue between two controllers. Swift. Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVOVW.png) .

I was trying to make a weather app. So when the user presses the date, it should show details on the other controller.

Here is my controller:

```
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

var weatherData = [WeatherModel]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getJSONData {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return weatherData.count

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
    for data in weatherData[indexPath.row].list{
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Bishkek " + data.dtTxt
    }
  return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "displayDetails", sender: self)
}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? WeatherViewController{
        destination.weatherModel = weatherData[(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!] 
       //I think this is where the error happens.
    }
}

func getJSONData(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
    if let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "weather", ofType: "json") {
            do{
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: filepath), options: .alwaysMapped)
                self.weatherData = try [JSONDecoder().decode(WeatherModel.self, from: data)]

            } catch let error{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completed()
            }
    } else {
        print("file not found")
    }
}
```

ERROR description:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController
>   loadView] instantiated view controller with identifier
>   "UIViewController-jT8-HX-aGV" from storyboard "Main", but didn't get a
>   UITableView.'

Comment: What's the base class of your view controller, is it a a `UIViewController` or `UITableViewController`?

Comment: @AhmadF it is UIViewController. Any ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: Possibly Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32875298/storyboard-main-but-didnt-get-a-uitableview-when-using-uitableviewcontroller https://stackoverflow.com/a/40024897/5501940

Comment: @AhmadF it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you attach screenshot of storyboard

Comment: @LalKrishna I added a link to a screenshot. please take a look.

Comment: Change the class parent to `UITableViewController `

Comment: @LalKrishna thanks. but it gives me these errors: Cannot override with a stored property 'tableView', Setter for 'tableView' with Objective-C selector 'setTableView:' conflicts with setter for 'tableView' from superclass 'UITableViewController' with the same Objective-C selector, Getter for 'tableView' with Objective-C selector 'tableView' conflicts with getter for 'tableView' from superclass 'UITableViewController' with the same Objective-C selector

Comment: You created `UITableViewController` in storyboard & created class for `UIViewController`. `UITableViewController` its self have` tableview` property, and you don't need to create it explicitly. May be the error because of this.

Comment: @LalKrishna didn't get you.